# Why is my data returning null when trying to call a web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am in the process of coding a console app in C# to call an API with the end goal of using dapper to put said data into a database. I have multiple API endpoints where some are working and some of returning null values. The following code is an example of an endpoint that returns a null value. Here is the code

```
using APIFootballDataRetrieval.Response;
using Newtonsoft.Json;[enter image description here][1]
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace APIFootballDataRetrieval
{
    class Program
    {
        
        static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key", "value");

               
                var response = await _client.GetAsync(Constants.CountriesEndpoint);
                
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);

                
                CountriesResponse CountriesResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CountriesResponse>(responseBody);

                Console.WriteLine($"This is the country name ");
                

            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw e;
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

here is the response code

```
using APIFootballDataRetrieval.Models;
using APIFootballDataRetrieval.Response;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace APIFootballDataRetrieval.Response
{
    public class CountriesResponse
    {
        public string Get { get; set; }
        public List<CountryResponse> Response { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Following Response code to nest deeper

```
using APIFootballDataRetrieval.Models;
using APIFootballDataRetrieval.Response;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace APIFootballDataRetrieval.Response
{
    public class CountryResponse
    {
        public List<Country> Country { get; set; }
        // This is where the API stops mapping and returns a NULL

    }
}
```

& finally the last code that models the api data

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using APIFootballDataRetrieval.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace APIFootballDataRetrieval.Models
{
    public class Country
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        //public string Flag { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have been stuck trying to fix this bug for a week already and have no clue what it could be. I add watches on the CountriesResponse to see if the data maps correctly but it stops mapping correctly at the final step of the proccess. I have also added a note in the code to help you guys see where the code stops working.

Here is the ResponseBody
[ResponseBody](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxYlp.jpg)

Comment: When you debug, what is `responseBody`?  Is the problem in getting the response from the API, or is the problem in deserializing that response to your object?

Comment: As an aside... This is an anti-pattern: `throw e;`  It's removing useful information from the original exception.  To re-throw the original exception as-is, just use `throw;`  Or, since the exception isn't being handled in any way, just remove the try/catch entirely and let the original exception surface.

Comment: I highly doubt that API will return a JSON object that looks like `{get:"some value", "response": [{name:"nl", code:"nl"},{name:"de",code:"de"}]}` but that is what your model classes expect, hence the null because there is no data in the response that maps to your model classes.

Comment: Use Postman or Fiddler to inspect the return body.

Comment: @David The problem is in deserializing the response. I get the response perfectly. For example, when i inspect my watches, everything comes back fine. I have a list of 134 countries but when i inspect further, each 134 reponses is null inside. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: As asked earlier, what does responseBody look like after the api call in debug - in order to deserialize the class must match the format in responseBody.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger Just added the responseBody img in the post

Comment: @Alex please share  output string for this statement " var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();"

Comment: Just looking through that image, your response looks like a List<Country> instead of List<List<Country>> which is what your List<CountryResponse> actually is. Might be missing something.

Comment: I added an img of the ResponseBody at the bottom

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON structure is (among other properties that the code isn't interested in), essentially this:

```
{
  "get": "string",
  "response": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "code": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

This does not match your C# model structure.  In that structure you are expecting this:

```
{
  "get": "string",
  "response": [
    {
      "country": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "code": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Basically you have an additional nested array structure in your models.  You are expecting `response` to be an array of objects containing a property called `country` which is an array of objects containing your `name/code` objects.  But the JSON has no such object with a `country` property.

Your model structure needs to match the JSON:

```
public class CountriesResponse
{
    public string Get { get; set; }
    public List<Country> Response { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

Essentially... `Response` is a list of countries, not a list of lists of countries.